# Is it possible to arrive to Myanmar at Myawaddy land crossing with an e-visa and no transport ticket now?

Tags: visas, e-visas, myanmar

Is it possible to arrive to Myanmar at Myawaddy land crossing with an e-visa and no transport ticket now?

Hi,

I have a Swedish (EU) passport. I want to check if it is possible to make an e-visa for Myanmar and arrive at Myawaddy through the land crossing without having a flight or bus ticket now (I want to cycle across the border).